# How to get username to Resourcename in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have table

```
Resource

ResourceId |  ResourceName |username   | password     
  1        |   raghu       |   aaaa    |  ******
  2        |   anil        |   bbbb    |  ******          

BugHistory

BugHisoryId | FixedByID  | AssignedByID
   1        |    2       |    1
   2        |    1       |    2
```

whos the login name same name username to get the Resourcename.
`FixedByIdforeign key(FixedById) reference Resource(ResourceId)`

**my controller code**

```
public ActionResult BugHistory(BugTracker_DataHelper bugdatahelepr, string loginname, string EmployeName)
{
    Session["UserName"] = "aaaa";
    loginname = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    //bugdatahelepr.Username = loginname.ToString();
    //var username = bugdatahelepr.Username;

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MvcBugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ResourceName from Resources where UserName =" + loginname, connection);       

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        bugdatahelepr.FixedByID = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ResourceName"]);
        //updatemodel.ProjectId = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ProjectId"]);
    }
    else
    {
        dr.Close();
    }
    dr.Close();
    connection.Close();

    //ViewBag.BugHistoryId = new SelectList(ToStatusDropdown(), "BugHistoryId", "ToStatus");
    //ViewData.AssignedToID=new SelectList()

    return View();
}
```

**My view code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>BugHistory</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

     <%: ViewBag.Title = "BugHistory"%>
     <% using (Html.BeginForm())
     { %>      
      <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>      

        <fieldset>
        <legend>BugHistory</legend>

       <div class="editor-label">
           <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.FixedByID)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.FixedByID)%>
            <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FixedByID)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
       <%:Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Resolution)%>
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
       <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.Resolution)%>
       <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resolution)%>
     </div>
       <%: Html.DropDownList("BugHistoryId", (SelectList)ViewBag.BugHistoryId, "--Select Project--")%>
       <%: Html.ValidationMessage("BugHistoryId")%>
       </fieldset> 

       <% }%> 
        <form action="AssignProject.aspx" method="post">  
            <p> <input type="submit" value="insert" /></p> 
             </form>           


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**am getting Error**

`Invalid column name 'aaaa'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'raghu'.

Source Error: 


Line 270:            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ResourceName from Resources where UserName =" + loginname, connection);       
Line 271:          
Line 272:            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Line 273:            
Line 274:            if (dr.Read())


Source File:     C:\Raghu\Gridview_BugTracker\Gridview_BugTracker\Controllers\ProjectsController.cs    Line: 272
```

when am login the page username aaaa get the Resourcename .Can anyone help me do this?

```
IN veiw page i Diplay like this

FixedBYID -----------raghu <---Lable in disabale

AssignedBY ID-------- anil <----dropdownlist in disable
```

Comment: From the error, it looks like the problem is it is trying to find the column `aaaa` in the database, instead of column `username`.

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie...this is my query  "select ResourceName from Resources where UserName =" + loginname,

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie..  am get username same in database even am getting this type error came ..what i shoud do ..

Comment: It looks like @Marnix van Valen answered your question, aside from that, do NOT concatenate strings to build SQL queries (like he said) this gives a hacker the option to use a SQL statement as their username and it will execute against your database (SQL Injection.)

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things that you should improve in this code. First off, always (and I mean always) wrap connections and datareaders in a `using` statement.

Second, do **NOT** concatenate strings to build SQL queries. This will open you up to SQL insertion attacks. Instead you should use parameters.

Now, for the error you are seeing. You are simply appending the user name to the query, this will make your query look like this:

```
select ResourceName from Resources where UserName =aaaa
```

The user name is not quoted which means the database server will try to look for a column named 'aaaa'. Which is exactly the error message you are seeing.

Your data access code should look something like this:

```
using( var connection = new SqlConnection(@".... your connection string here ...") )
{
  connection.Open();

  var cmd = new SqlCommand("select ResourceName from Resources where UserName =@username", connection);       
  cmd.Parameters.Add( name, DbType.String ).Value = loginName;

  using( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
  {
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        // read your data here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because:

- you're not using quotation marks - in sql string constants need to be enclosed in ''
- you're doing it wrong: you should be using parameters instead of concatenating strings